# OpenLayers3 - Add text labels to polygon

Tags: styles, openlayers-3

I have the following code to get a feature from a `.geojson`, and color the polygons (which are squares in my case) according to values in the `.geojson` file.

```
var myStyle = function(feature) {
  var id = feature.get('featureName');
  fill.setColor(id >= 0 && id <= 0.10 ? coloringFunction1(feature): id >= 0.10 && id <= 1.00 ? coloringFunction2(feature):coloringFunction3(feature));
  return style;
};
```

I want to show the `id` value as well, along with the colors, so I have done like the following:

```
    var myStyle = function(feature) {
  var id = feature.get('featureName');
  fill.setColor(id >= 0 && id <= 0.10 ? coloringFunction1(feature): id >= 0.10 && id <= 1.00 ? coloringFunction2(feature):coloringFunction3(feature));

// To show the text

text: new ol.style.Text({
     textAlign: "Center",
     textBaseline: "Middle",
     font: 'Normal 12px Arial',
     text: id,
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: 'black'
     }),
     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
       color: 'black',
       width: 3
     }),
   })
  return style;
};
```

However, it's not working at all. So my question is: How to show the extracted feature value with its color?

Comment: You might find a solution at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html

Comment: @sudhirshakya Thank you for comment. I got to somewhere after taking away a lot of unwanted code. However, I faced a problem that the feature I want to get is a number, not a text, and that is causing another problem.